# How to correct this error?

Tags: java, android, sql, jax-rs

I am developing android App and I am using RestFul Webservices.I have used multiPartEntity to send data from client side to server.I don't have any error in client side.but I have error in my server side code.can you help me?

**My client side code is:**

```
                    multipart.addPart("hotelName",new StringBody(hotelName));
                    multipart.addPart("userName",new StringBody(userName));
                    multipart.addPart("password",new StringBody(password));
                    multipart.addPart("tinNumber",new StringBody(tinNumber));
                    multipart.addPart("Address",new StringBody(Address));
                    multipart.addPart("mobile_No",new StringBody(mobile_No));
                    multipart.addPart("email_Id",new StringBody(email_Id));
                    multipart.addPart("star_Rate",new StringBody(star_Rate));                       
                    multipart.addPart("imagePath",new InputStreamBody(getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse("file://"+imagePath)),imageName+".jpg"));

                    httppost.setEntity(multipart);
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

**My Server side Code is**

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void postHotel(MultiPart hotelParams)
        throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into hotel (name,user_name,password,tin_number,address,mobile_no,email,rating,hotel_logo) values('"
            +hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(0)
            + "','"
            + hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(1)
            + "','"
            + hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(2)
            + "',"
            + hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(3)
            + ",'"
            + hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(4)
            + "',"
            + hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(5)
            + ",'"
            + hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(6)
            + "','"
            + hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(7) + "','" + hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(8) + "');");
```

**My error is like:**

```
SERVE: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.multipart.FormDataBodyPart@9d2f26,'com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataBodyPart@18' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2562)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1583)
    at com.orderfree.Resource.HotelRegsiter.postHotel(HotelRegsiter.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

**Please help me friends**

Comment: Put space between `hotel` and ...: `hotel (user_name,password) values (`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a sql syntax error try to print the values of `hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(0)`

and  `hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(1)`

1.Try to Check whether you are getting strings or not.

2.Try to check whitespaces in between sql query

3.Try to edit ur code by putting something like this

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void postHotel(@FormDataParam("user_name") String userName
                   @FormDataParam("password") String password)
        throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into hotel(user_name,password)values('"
            +userName
            + "','"
            +password
            + "');
```

Comment: i didn't get string value.i got a result as BodyPart from multiPartEntity

Comment: don't use multipart try to get userName and password as part of post request.And extract the values at server side using @RequestParam

Comment: I have passed image from client to server through MultiPartEntity. but I didn't put on this code.so only i use MultiPartEntity can you correct that?

Comment: I have edited my answer try to replace the code with which i have edited in my answer that might helpful for you

Comment: :thank you friend.but i need to get value from MultipartEntity.i have updated my Question.please help me

Comment: Try to use this annotation at method parameterlevel @Multipart(value = "userName", type = "text/plain") String userName,

Comment: I didn't get you Naveen.pls can give brief example?pls

Comment: Which Restfulservices implementation you are using I mean jersey impl or other?

Comment: i am using jersey friend

Answer (score 0):

Why do you are using multipart for this purpose?
Please use only two args, user and password. I recommend to you start with this easy solution:

```
   @Path("/user/{username}/{password}")
   public void postHotel(@PathParam("username") String username, @PathParam("password") String password) {
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into hotel(username,password)values('"
        +hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(0)
        + "','"
        + hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(1)
        + "');
```

Comment: I have passed image from client to server through MultiPartEntity. but I didn't put on this code.so only i use MultiPartEntity can you correct that?

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void postHotel(MultiPart hotelParams)
        throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into hotel(user_name,password)values('"
            +hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(0)
            + "','"
            + hotelParams.getBodyParts().get(1)
            + "'");
```