# Image store in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, performance

I have added image to MultiPartEntity like

```
MultiPartEntity multipart=new MultiPartEntity();
multipart.addPart("imagePath",new InputStreamBody(getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse("file://"+imagePath)),imageName+".jpg"));

httppost.setEntity(multipart);

response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Now i have to get **"imagePath"** value from server side and store it into Mysql.I am using Jersey.how can I get **"imagePath"** value?

Comment: imagePath is where the image is stored in the device not on the server.

Comment: @dannyroa image is stored in the device

Comment: Why are you unable to access the path of the image? Is it from camera or gallery?

Comment: @dannyroa: i am taking from gallery

Comment: OnActivityResult should give you the Uri of the selected image. You can get image path from Uri.

Comment: @dannyroa: I have given my problem detailed on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394169/how-to-correct-this-error] Page.can you visit and give solution for me?

Comment: @dannyroa: hmmm i can get Uri of selected image and I added into MultiPartEntity.now my problem is how should i get "ImagePath" value on server side?

Comment: Why do you need the ImagePath from the server?